# How do I embed a 'YouTube Gaming' video with the IFrame API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, video-embedding

I want to embed a gaming live stream on my website and play it using JavaScript.

Using the [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), I can dynamically embed and control YouTube videos. YouTube Gaming has [its own version of the player](https://gaming.youtube.com/embed/6Ic7c8Jns8Y) that links to gaming.youtube.com instead of www.youtube.com. But there's no mention of how to make the API use it.

I tried using https://gaming.youtube.com/iframe_api, but it doesn't exist.

How do I embed a YouTube Gaming video with the IFrame API?

Comment: Why do you need javascript in particular ?

Comment: I need to use JavaScript because I want the video to auto-play muted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pass an undocumented `host` property to the constructor. It seems to work fine.

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    host: "https://gaming.youtube.com",
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `gaming.youtube.com`.
`www.youtube.com` works !

Comment: This is just a wrapper around the IFrame API. I already have the code to embed the YouTube player; I just need to get it to use the _Gaming_ version (i.e., with `<iframe src="https://gaming.youtube.com/embed/xxx" ...`).

Comment: You don't need to use gaming.youtube.com as www.youtube.com is the same. Just try :)

I've edited my answer

Comment: That's my current solution. Yes, it works. However, the button to watch on YouTube links to www.youtube.com, which still has the old look.